# WooCommerce conditional tags not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I am trying to use a mixture of Wordpress and Wooommerce conditional tags to load content on certain pages within my site. However, the WooCommerce conditional tags do not seem to have any effect. In the below example, I am trying to NOT load some code if the user is logged in, or if they are on any WooCommerce page. It works if logged in, but does not take effect on WooCommerce pages?

I have also tried `!is_checkout()` and `!is_account_page()`, and neither take effect either?

```
<?php
// Do not display code if user is logged in OR on any woocommerce pages
if ( !is_user_logged_in() || !is_woocommerce() ) {
    // CODE HERE
} ?>
```

Comment: where did you place your code?

Comment: It's in 2 places, once in functions.php to load a script, and again in the header markup to load the html. Should work.

Comment: It should work so: if user is logged in and when he is not on products/prod. categories/shop pages/subpages. if user is logged out. where it doesnt work from conditions I mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation (and I'm still not sure on the logic here), it turns out that we need to replace the OR `||` statements with AND `&&` statements.

More than one `!` with an OR `||` will always equal true because that string variable will only equal one thing and not be the other.

This is tested and works, but can anybody shed light on the logic? I had assumed that replacing all `||` with `&&` would not cause to execute the statement only if all conditions all TRUE?

Here is the updated and functioning code:

replacing all || with && will not cause to execute the statement in parenthesis only if all conditions all TRUE?

Here is the updated and functioning code:

```
<?php
// Do not display code if user is logged in OR on any woocommerce pages
if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_woocommerce() ) {
    // CODE HERE
} ?>
```